# 120V and 240V outlet in same box

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am installing a new 240V circuit for an EV charger. I would like to put the outlet for this in a 2-gang box that would also have a 120V outlet. I'm in California. Is this OK?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! What kind of EV plug are you installing? Are we talking about a NEMA 14-50 outlet with ground? (that's [Tesla's preferred plug](https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/downloads/US/universalmobileconnector_nema_14-50.pdf) at any rate)

Comment: Its a NEMA 6-20 plug (for a Duosida Level 2 240V/16A charger)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 120V and 240V can cohabitate.  Both of those are classified as Class 1 circuits.  The highest voltage present in the box will be 240V, and with any normal wiring (NM, THHN in conduit, MC, etc.) all the wiring will have insulation rated well above that voltage.

However, depending on the plug on your charger, it may not fit in half a 2-gang.

Comment: Yes, a real problem is that the EV charger *plug* may foul/eclipse the adjacent 5-15 sockets, making it impossible to plug in both charger and other stuff.

Comment: @Harper -- fortunately, a 6-20P shouldn't do that as it's the same size as a 5-20P :)

Comment: It's definitely not going to be happy with a GFCI next to it (which is prob required); just put two boxes. I've never seen a circle next to the rectangle of a Decora slot on a surface mount coverplate so you're out of luck anyway.